# couchdb validation functions

Tags: validation, permissions, couchdb

I'm searching for ways to customize ouputs of couch-db to non-authenticated users.

I found loads of documentation about `validate_doc_update` - which implies that couchdb is aware of the user-context, and his roles.

but I'm looking for something like `validate_doc_view`, or `validate_doc_retrieve`, where I can see that the user is asking for documents or views that he should not get.

For example - in a forum - see private messages of other users.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lists and shows to filter with the req.userCTX:
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html

Comment: I'm afraid that the list function is a little too late. Can I change the startkey and endkey in the list function, or just filter the results?